# Is it possible to use the SQL DATEADD function but exclude dates from a table in the calculation?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use the DATEADD function but exclude dates from a table?

We already have a table with all dates we need to exclude.  Basically, I need to add number of days to a date but exclude dates within a table.

Example:  Add **5 days** to **01/08/2021**.  Dates **03/08/2021** and **04/08/2021** exist in the exclusion table. So, resultant date should be:  ***08/08/2021***.

Thank you

Comment: Please add sample data to make this a complete question.

Comment: You can use the IN clause

Comment: Seems you really want to "skip" these dates for your period calculation. If you search for discussions about working (or business) dates you will find various solutions and suggestions for this. A calendar table is a big help for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have all the non working days dates (weekends) and public holidays on a table.  But can't find a solution anywhere including stackoverflow where I could specify a date and a number and it'll calculate the working day date excluding public holidays i.e. add that number to the specified date and return date.  The period calculation must exclude the dates within the holidays table.  The holidays table already has weekend dates.  hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a "wonky" solution, but it works. Firstly we use a tally to create a Calendar table of dates, that exclude your dates in the table, then we get the *n*th row, where *n* is the number of days to add:

```sql
DECLARE @DaysToAdd int = 5,
        @StartDate date = '20210801';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --Up to 1,000
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,T.I, @StartDate) AS D,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.I) AS I
    FROM Tally T
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.DatesTable DT
                      WHERE DT.YourDate = DATEADD(DAY,T.I, @StartDate)))
SELECT D
FROM Calendar
WHERE I = @DaysToAdd+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A best solution is probably a calendar table.

But if you're willing to traverse through every date, then a recursive CTE can work. It would require tracking the total iterations and another column to substract if any traversed date was in the table. The exit condition uses the total difference.

An example dataset would be:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(mydate date); INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('20210803'), ('20210804');
```

And an example function run in it's own batch:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_getDays (@mydate date, @daysadd int)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @newdate date;

WITH CTE(num, diff, mydate) AS (
  SELECT 0 AS [num]
        ,0 AS [diff]
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 0, @mydate) [mydate]
    
  UNION ALL

  SELECT num + 1 AS [num]
        ,CTE.diff +  
               CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, num+1, @mydate) IN (SELECT mydate FROM mytable) 
                     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
         AS [diff]
        ,DATEADD(DAY, num+1, @mydate) [mydate]
    FROM CTE
  WHERE (CTE.diff + 
               CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, num+1, @mydate) IN (SELECT mydate FROM mytable) 
                     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) <= @daysadd
)

SELECT @newdate = (SELECT MAX(mydate) AS [mydate] FROM CTE);
RETURN @newdate;
END
```

Running the function:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_getDays('20210801', 5)
```

Produces output, which is the MAX(mydate) from the function:

```
----------
2021-08-08
```

For reference the MAX(mydate) is taken from this dataset:

```
n           diff        mydate
----------- ----------- ----------
0           0           2021-08-01
1           1           2021-08-02
2           1           2021-08-03
3           1           2021-08-04
4           2           2021-08-05
5           3           2021-08-06
6           4           2021-08-07
7           5           2021-08-08
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the IN clause.

To perform the test, I used a [W3Schools Test DB](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_date_add)

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(BirthDate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) FROM Employees WHERE FirstName NOT IN (Select FirstName FROM Employees WHERE FirstName LIKE 'N%')
```

This query shows all the birth dates + 10 days except for the only employee with name starting with N (Nancy)

Comment: This isn't valid T-SQL.

Comment: didnt noticed, anyway, good enough to give an idea on how to do it

Comment: Apart from it's not, because it's not valid for the RDBMS the OP is asking about. The use of `DATE_ADD`'s syntax is nothing like `DATEADD`'s

Comment: This function might add 10 days (in a different DBMS), but OP is asking to add days to some date AND skip certain dates that are present in a table.